# Result Set object has no attribute 'find'. I am again and again running into this error when the given attribute exists in form of <img>

Tags: python

```
from helium import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers={
    'UserAgent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'
    }

url = 'https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=books&rs=typed'
browser = start_chrome(url, headless=True)

soup= bs(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
scrape=soup.find_all('div',class_="XiG zI7 iyn Hsu")
Images=scrape.find('img',)

print(Images)
```

I am including the inspect element of site I am scraping as a link:

[image: obnoxious image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: The error message is quite clear.  `find_all()` returns a set of results, which does not have a `.find()` method.

Comment: Please suggest how can I edit it to get the desired result that is all the <img>tags on page.

Comment: If you want all the img tags, then do a `find_all()` on the img tag.  What is the difficulty?